# Adding information to a Jlist from a JTextfield

Tags: java, swing, jlist

My intention is that when I click enter in the jTextfield the content String goes to the JLIST. I view several codes with jlist.addElement, but my Netbeans doesn't recognize that.

[image]

The Jtextfield is : TickNuevo
That string is:
                 String ticket = TickNuevo.getText();

```
private void TickNuevoKeyPressed(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                     


    if(evt.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER) 
    {
        i++;
        String ticket = TickNuevo.getText();
        if(!"".equals(ticket)) 
        {
                **Adding the text into the jlist fails**
                listesp.add(TickNuevo.getText());

        }
        else
        {
            anadirticket.setText("Introduzca un ticket válido");
        }
        TickNuevo.setText("");
    }
}
```

I get this error in my code:

[image]

listesp is the Jlist

Comment: You really should use a `ActionListener` instead of a `KeyListener`, see [How to Write an Action Listeners](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html) for more details. I'd also encourage you to have a look at [How to Use Lists](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html)l. Data in a `JList` is generally managed through the `ListModel`

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it could be answered by reading one of the many tutorials on the subject, [How to Use Lists](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html) for example

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As MadProgrammer suggested, make model for your list so you can add and remove items.

```
DefaultListModel listModel = new DefaultListModel();
list.setModel(listModel);
```

When you want to add item to your list, you just need to add it to your listModel

```
listModel.addElement("Element Goes Here");
```

Comment: Thanks Nayriva, I tried that but I cant relate that DefaultListModel to my list. I created that list with GUI and I dont know where to transform my graphic created list into a DefaultListModel.I have this allready created: private javax.swing.JList<String> listesp;

Comment: You can't transform list into DefaultListModel. DefaultListModel can be added to your list as its "attribute" you will just need to write those two lines in place where you are initializing your list. If you do it this way, you can use "getListModel()" method to extract model from list. Anyway, try making your List global variable.
If you mean it like "i have created it in some GUI designer and i don't have variable for list, try create list in your code"

Comment: Thanks Nayriva, I got it.

Comment: @Furiwel, (1-)  `I tried that but I cant relate that DefaultListModel to my list.` This is what happens when you spoon feed the answer, people get lazy and don't take the time to understand the suggestion. MadProgrammer provided a link to the Swing tutorial on `How to Use Lists` for a reason. It contains a working example that does exactly as asked. Take the time to read the tutorial and learn by example.